# Better Replication to move columns encrypted using SQL Always encryption

Tags: sql-server, replication, database-replication, transactional-replication, always-encrypted

I have currently using Transaction replication in my production database and replicating the same database for internal purpose.

Due to GDPR compliance, we are going to encrypt our database customer information columns using Always Encryption.

I have found some articles says Always encryption doesn't support Transactional replication.

Are any other alternative solutions available for this? like a better option for transaction replication

Please suggest any other replication method to move the encrypted tables to another server.

Note: We have currently replicating nearly 350+ tables, so using manual jobs or queries is difficult to implement.

SQL Server Version: 2016

Comment: Instead of articles, check [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017#feature-details)  `The following features do not work on encrypted columns:

Transactional or merge replication
Distributed queries (linked servers)` .

Comment: You don't need encryption for GDPR though, unless stealing the DB disks is a common occurence. GDPR is about what you *store* on the disks, for how long and when it's deleted, and who has access to the data. Access is primarily enforced by using limited access accounts, restricting access through permissions and obviously, not using `sa` to connect to the database. Data retention or deletion is the job of DBAs and/or batch jobs. Encryption doesn't cover any of this

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Interesting view. I do agree that filesystem encryption only protects against physical theft. Furthermore when a database server itself is compromised the encryption keys of database-table encryption solutions is also compromised, so that does not help much either. However in the GDPR encryption is mentioned 4 times, among which: "the controller and the processor shall implement appropriate technical and organisational measures to ensure a level of security appropriate to the risk, including inter alia as appropriate:(a)the pseudonymisation and encryption of personal data;"

Answer (score 0):

Your question asks for alternatives to transactional replication.  Have you considered Availability Groups?  The setup seems more complex than replication, but it can be used to accomplish a similar goal.

Ahmad Yaseen shows how to [add a database with TDE (Transparent Data Encryption) to an availability group](https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-add-a-tde-encrypted-user-database-to-an-always-on-availability-group/).  With SQL 2016 this will require a cluster.  In 2017 and newer you could accomplish this goal without a cluster.

> The Add Database Wizard and New Availability Group Wizard for AlwaysOn Availability Groups do not support adding databases that are already encrypted using the TDE encryption to an Availability Group. If you try to add the TDE_Test database, which is encrypted using TDE, by the Add Database Wizard, the wizard will show you that this is not applicable as the database contains an encryption key as below:
>
> This means that we need to add the database to the Availability group manually. We need to perform full backup and transaction log backup for the TDE_Test database, copy it and restore it with NORECOVERY at the DB42VS secondary replica.

This will create a similar but different solution than replication.  You will get all the transactions replicated to the secondary database, but the secondary database will be essentially a mirror to the Primary.  As opposed to picking which tables to replicate with transactional replication.